# Binding input of list of objects without knowing the number of objects the user will feed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to bind an input of list items to a `List` object but it seems that the only way this can be done is if I initialized my `List` with a certain number of those objects and then bind the properties from the input to the null properties of the objects in my `List`

So for example, the following will give out of bounds exception unless I add some `PersonInputModel` objects to `PersonInput`

### Index ViewPage

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <form method="post">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="PersonInput[0].Name" />

        <label for="age">Age</label>
        <input type="number" asp-for="PersonInput[0].Age" />
    </form>
</div>
```

### Index PageModel

```
 public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

        
        [BindProperty]
        public IList<PersonInputModel> PersonInput { get; set; } = new List<PersonInputModel>();


        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }
    }
```

### PersonInputModel

```
public class PersonInputModel
    {
        
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public Person ToPerson()
        {
            return new Person
            {
                Name = Name,
                Age = Age
            };
        }
    }
```

But what if the user can add more input forms to add more than one person ? What if the user feeds more input than the number of objects in `PersonInput` list ? How can I make my input list dynamic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a work demo , you can refer to it.

Person.cs

```
public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

PersonInputModel

```
public class PersonInputModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }
        public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    }
```

IndexModel

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
       
        [BindProperty]
        public PersonInputModel PersonInputModel { get; set; } 
        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
             
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public void OnPost(PersonInputModel personInputModel)
        {

        }
    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

    <form  method="post">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="PersonInputModel.Name" />

        <label for="age">Age</label>
        <input type="number" asp-for="PersonInputModel.Age" /> 
        <button type="button" onclick="myfunction()">Add Person</button>
          
        <table id="myTable" style="display: none;" >
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>age</th>           
        </tr>
        </table>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" >Create</button>
        </div>
     </div>
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
        var mytab = document.getElementById("myTable");
        var i = 0;
        function myfunction() {
            document.getElementById("myTable").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("myTable").insertRow(-1).innerHTML =
                '<td>  <input type="text" name="PersonInputModel.Persons[' +i + '].Name" />       </td><td> <input type="number" name="PersonInputModel.Persons[' + i + '].Age" />    </td>';
            i++;
           
        }
  </script>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, man. It seems that it's working because `PersonInputModel` is put as a parameter for the `onPost` handler. I am curious though, is that the only way to do it ?

Comment: You are welcome！You can also not put PersonInputModel as a parameter for the onPost handler. Just use it. Because you have used `[BindProperty]` bind the model.

Comment: Such as:   [HttpPost]public void OnPost()
        {
            var person = PersonInputModel;  
        }